# clogit output producing NAs but partially show up when I use cbind

Tags: r, logistic-regression, cbind

(updated)
Hey Stack Overflowers,

I'm trying to run a series of MLM fixed-effect logistic regressions with R's `clogit` function. When I add additional covariates to my model, the summary output shows NAs. But, when I used the `cbind` function, some of the missing covariate coefficients show up.

Here's my model 1 equation and output:

```
> model1 <- clogit(chldwork~lag_aspgrade_binned+age+strata(childid), data=finaletdtlag, method = 'exact')
> summary(model1)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(rep(1, 2686L), chldwork) ~ lag_aspgrade_binned + 
    age + strata(childid), data = finaletdtlag, method = "exact")

  n= 2686, number of events= 2287 

                                       coef exp(coef) se(coef)       z Pr(>|z|)    
lag_aspgrade_binnedhigh school      1.04156   2.83363  0.52572   1.981  0.04757 *  
lag_aspgrade_binnedno primary       1.31891   3.73935  0.89010   1.482  0.13841    
lag_aspgrade_binnedprimary some hs  0.85000   2.33964  0.56244   1.511  0.13072    
lag_aspgrade_binnedsome college     1.28607   3.61855  0.41733   3.082  0.00206 ** 
age                                -0.39600   0.67301  0.03105 -12.753  < 2e-16 ***
```

Here's my model two equation:

```
model2
<- clogit(chldwork~lag_aspgrade_binned+age+sex+chldeth+typesite+selfwlth+enroll+strata(childid), data=finaletdtlag, method = 'exact')
summary(model2)
```

Here's the summary output:

```
> summary(model2)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(rep(1, 2686L), chldwork) ~ lag_aspgrade_binned + 
    age + sex + chldeth + typesite + selfwlth + enroll + strata(childid), 
    data = finaletdtlag, method = "efron")

  n= 2675, number of events= 2277 
   (11 observations deleted due to missingness)

                                       coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
lag_aspgrade_binnedhigh school      0.32943   1.39018  0.13933  2.364   0.0181 *  
lag_aspgrade_binnedno primary       0.46553   1.59286  0.25154  1.851   0.0642 .  
lag_aspgrade_binnedprimary some hs  0.33477   1.39762  0.15728  2.128   0.0333 *  
lag_aspgrade_binnedsome college     0.36268   1.43718  0.11792  3.076   0.0021 ** 
age                                -0.07638   0.92647  0.01020 -7.486 7.11e-14 ***
sex1                                     NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
chldeth2                                 NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
chldeth3                                 NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
chldeth4                                 NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
chldeth6                                 NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
chldeth7                                 NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
chldeth8                                 NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
chldeth9                                 NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
chldeth99                                NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
typesite1                                NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
selfwlth1                           0.04031   1.04113  0.29201  0.138   0.8902    
selfwlth2                           0.11971   1.12717  0.28736  0.417   0.6770    
selfwlth3                           0.07928   1.08251  0.29189  0.272   0.7859    
selfwlth4                           0.05717   1.05884  0.30231  0.189   0.8500    
selfwlth5                           0.39709   1.48750  0.43653  0.910   0.3630    
selfwlth99                               NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
enroll1                            -0.20443   0.81511  0.08890 -2.300   0.0215 *  
enroll88                                 NA        NA  0.00000     NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

But here's what happens when I use the cbind function to show all of my models next to each other. Note, that coefficients sex through chldeth99 are not in model one.

`cbind` results:

```
> cbind(coef(model1), (coef(model2)), coef(model3)) #creating side by side list of all model coefficients
                                         [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
lag_aspgrade_binnedhigh school      1.0415583  0.27198991  0.32827106
lag_aspgrade_binnedno primary       1.3189131  0.37986205  0.46103492
lag_aspgrade_binnedprimary some hs  0.8499958  0.27831739  0.33256493
lag_aspgrade_binnedsome college     1.2860726  0.30089261  0.36214068
age                                -0.3960015 -0.06233958 -0.07653464
sex1                                1.0415583          NA          NA
chldeth2                            1.3189131          NA          NA
chldeth3                            0.8499958          NA          NA
chldeth4                            1.2860726          NA          NA
chldeth6                           -0.3960015          NA          NA
chldeth7                            1.0415583          NA          NA
chldeth8                            1.3189131          NA          NA
chldeth9                            0.8499958          NA          NA
chldeth99                           1.2860726          NA          NA
typesite1                          -0.3960015          NA          NA
selfwlth1                           1.0415583  0.03245507  0.04424493
selfwlth2                           1.3189131  0.09775395  0.12743276
selfwlth3                           0.8499958  0.06499650  0.08854499
selfwlth4                           1.2860726  0.05038224  0.07092755
selfwlth5                          -0.3960015  0.32162830  0.38079232
selfwlth99                          1.0415583          NA          NA
enroll1                             1.3189131 -0.16966609 -0.30366842
enroll88                            0.8499958          NA          NA
sex1:enroll1                        1.2860726  0.27198991  0.24088361
sex1:enroll88                      -0.3960015  0.37986205          NA
```

Much gratitude for any insights. Wishing you all the best as another year wraps up--special shoutout to those currently in school still on the grind.

Comment: *Note, that coefficients sex through chldeth99 are not in model one.* ... Did you post `model1`? I only see `model2` defined.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can edit your post to show exactly what part of the output is unexpected.

Comment: I just added model 1 to the post. Also, the covariates of sex through childeth variables that appeared in wave one and then I inserted the matching values into subsequent waves because they're background charactersitics. I was expecting to get coefficients and NAs when trying to fit my model with them.